# Showing Zenity popup to all users

Tags: ubuntu, zenity

I want to show a zenity popup (or other graphical display) to other users on my machine when I log in via SSH. How can I achieve this to pop up for other users?

When I connect via SSH it should show to logged in users, but also, if the users are not logged in when I connect, and subsequently log in, then when they log in (while I am connected) they should see the notification.

I expect I can write some file which is checked on user login to run the script after I connect, but it is the initial connection command which has me stumped.

Basically this is for my Home computer and I don't want my family switching it off while I am doing stuff!

Comment: The "initial connection command has me stumped" ... what do you mean?

Comment: Apologies, I simply mean the command, I can run that whenever I connect via SSH, and whenever a user logs in

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic outline for one way to do this, assuming you and your family members have bash as their login shell. Let's say you are user "joe" and your family consists of the users "user1", "user2", and "user3".

**In your .bash_login:**

```
for user in user1 user2 user3; do
    echo "JOE is logged in, do not turn power off" > /tmp/message.$user
done
```

**In your .bash_logout:**

```
for user in user1 user2 user3; do
    [ -f /tmp/message.$user ] && rm /tmp/message.$user
done
```

**Now, in each of the other user's .bash_login:**

```
export MSGFILE=/tmp/message.$USER
check_messages() {
  while [ 1 ]; do
    if [ -f $MSGFILE ]; then
        zenity --text-info --filename=$MSGFILE
        rm $MSGFILE
    fi
    sleep 60
  done
}

check_messages &
```

So, if userX is logged in, they will have a background task that checks for a new message once per minute.